# img CSS will not update onclick via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been banging my head against this for a few hours and am no closer to a solution than I was before. I am dynamically generating `<img>` tags, each with their own unique ID, via an AJAX call and JavaScript and giving them certain border colors upon generation (marking whether they are 'good' or 'bad`).

```
// the div that the screenshots go in
<div id ="screenshots_holder"> </div>


// the JS that is generating the screenshots

var screenshots_holder = document.getElementById("screenshots_holder");
var x = "";


for(i in data.screenshots) {

var image_name = data.screenshots[i].split("/")

x += '<img id="' + image_name[2] +'"src="/static/'; 
x += data.screenshots[i]; 
x += '" style = "height: auto; border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; border-color: #1ebe1e; max-width: 10%; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; "'; 
x += 'onclick="blueifyScreenshot(this.id)" >'; <-- the problem is here!!

}
screenshots_holder.innerHTML = x;
```

This above code worked just fine... minus the very last part where I add the `onclick` attribute!

I am trying to make it so that when I click on a screenshot, its border changes color, it scales just a bit, and adds a box-shadow, all of which is done through a JavaScript function called `blueifyScreenshot(id)` which takes the unique id of the image as a parameter so it can be grabbed through jQuery.

Right now, I can get the screenshot to do that when I hover over it but that's not permanent. Unfortunately, I cannot get any of my CSS changes to go through.

Right now I am grabbing each image element by a jQuery id selector. I know that this is working and `updated_id` is what it should be because I've verified it through HTML/JS breakpoints in the debugger and matched it to the screenshot that I want to change the border of.  `blueifyScreenshot` IS being called, but none of the CSS is changing no matter what I do.

I have tried using the `.css` method, which I know only works on existing elements, which my screenshots are.

```
function blueifyScreenshot(id) {

console.log("#" + id);
var updated_id = "#" + id;

// this isn't changing anything
$(updated_id).css({
   "border-color": "#0614d1 !important",
   "cursor" : "pointer" ,
   "transform": "scale(1.1)",
   "box-shadow": "0 0 12px #0614d1" });

}
```

I have tried adding a class with `.addClass()` and defining it in my .css sheet.

```
function blueifyScreenshot(id) {

console.log("#" + id);
var updated_id = "#" + id;

// this isn't changing anything either..
$(updated_id).addClass('selected_screenshot');

}
/* CSS */

.selected_screenshot {

    border-color: #0614d1 !important;
    cursor : pointer;
    transform: scale(1.1); 
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #0614d1; 
}
```

I have even tried updating the style attribute of the image with the `.attr()` method.

```
function blueifyScreenshot(id) {

console.log("#" + id);
var updated_id = "#" + id;

// and THIS wont change anything.
$(updated_id).attr('style', "height: auto; border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; border-color: #0614d1; max-width: 10%; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;");

}
```

None of this has worked and my screenshots do not change when I click on them. I've tried browsing through StackOverflow to see if other people had this issue and it looks like everyone was able to resolve their problems through the methods I've tried.

Anyone able to assist, or maybe spot something I have not?

Comment: well you probably want to add a space before the `o` in onclick and between your id and src attributes

Comment: You also define `x` inside the loop so you are only every going to get the last item to render.

Comment: Clarified. Thanks. I don't think there is an issue in my onclick attribute though because I know the function is being called.

Comment: Just to confirm, none of your image ids have spaces in them, right?

Comment: That's right. They have mutiple underscores, they have a .jpg attachment on the end... but there are no spaces.

Comment: can you verify jQuery is loaded/working?

Comment: I've used it elsewhere in my code so yes,  it's up and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reference the element

```
onclick="blueifyScreenshot(this)"
```

and toggle a class

```
function blueifyScreenshot(elem) {
  elem.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

Personally I would just use a dom method

```js
var images = [
  'http://placekitten.com/100/300',
  'http://placekitten.com/200/200',
  'http://placekitten.com/200/300',
  'http://placekitten.com/100/200'
]

var outElem = document.getElementById('out')

images.forEach(function(src) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.className = 'example'
  img.src = src
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('selected')
  })
  outElem.appendChild(img)
})
```

```css
img.example {
  height: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #1ebe1e;
  max-width: 10%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

img.example.selected {
  border-color: #0614d1 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #0614d1;
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: I tried to reference the element as you did and set it to`active` and made this little css block with this header.
`#screenshots_holder img:active
{
    border-color: #0614d1 !important;  
    cursor : pointer; 
    transform: scale(1.1); 
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #0614d1; 
}`

It still isn't working though.

Comment: Never mind! I ended up stylizing my screenshots so that when they are generated they have either a `good_screenshot` class or  a `bad_screenshot` class. Then I made a third class to be activated on selection and used `.toggle("selected_screenshot")` as you suggested and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for your easy and simple to understand suggestion!